# Changing Leaflet Base CRS using Proj4js

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, extents, wmts, proj4leaflet

I am trying to change the CRS of a web mapping service in Norway. The projection is [EPSG:25832](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832).

Here is the WMTS service: https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/norge-i-bilder/norge-i-bilder-wmts-euref89-utm32/61ed45e1-2ef3-4f94-873c-e9dcb6be4aa6

Here is the example from [Proj4Leaflet Documentation](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet):

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2400',
  '+lon_0=15.808277777799999 +lat_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +x_0=1500000.0 ' +
  '+y_0=0.0 +proj=tmerc +ellps=bessel +units=m ' +
  '+towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +no_defs',
 {
  resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048] // 3 example zoom level resolutions
 }
);
```

The WMS loads using the code below when the CRS information is not being used. The map centers on northern Norway but it should be centering near Oslo.

There is something wrong with the CRS information then or how I am using proj4.js?

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  resolutions: [
     131073, 65537, 32769, 16385, 8193, 4097, 2049, 1025, 513, 257, 
129, 
65, 33, 17, 9, 5, 3, 2
  ],
  origin: [-2000000.0, 9045984.0],
  bounds:  L.bounds( [-2000000.0, 3500000.0], [3545984.0, 9045984.0])
})

var key ='****************'

var map = L.map('mapid',{
zoomControl: false,
zoomSnap: 0.1,
// crs: crs,
continuousWorld: true,
worldCopyJump: false
}).setView([59.877812, 8.590628], 5);

var gkt = '***************';
var url = 
'http://gatekeeper{s}.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.nib_utm32_wmts_v2?&gkt='
+ gkt 
+'&layer=Nibcache_UTM32_EUREF89&style=default&tilematrixset=default028mm&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix={z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}';

var wms = new L.TileLayer(url, {
   subdomains: ['1', '2', '3'],
   maxZoom: 16,
   minZoom: 0,
   attribution: ''
 }).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Just have a look at the code in my answer below. It works and when map is shown it centers on Rjukan. Try it, including resolutions in the example.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you find the Bounds of your WMTS?

Typically (as per any OGC service) you'd make a GetCapabilities request.  Something like:

> https://gatekeeper1.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.nib_utm32_wmts_v2?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS&

but in this instance some other parameter is required.

In this situation, there is also published [metadata](https://www.geonorge.no/geonetwork/srv/nor/xml_iso19139?uuid=61ed45e1-2ef3-4f94-873c-e9dcb6be4aa6) that tells us the extents of the service:

```
<srv:extent>
    <gmd:EX_Extent>
        <gmd:geographicElement>
            <gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                    <gco:Decimal xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">2</gco:Decimal>
                </gmd:westBoundLongitude>
                <gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                    <gco:Decimal xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">33</gco:Decimal>
                </gmd:eastBoundLongitude>
                <gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                    <gco:Decimal xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">57</gco:Decimal>
                </gmd:southBoundLatitude>
                <gmd:northBoundLatitude>
                    <gco:Decimal xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">72</gco:Decimal>
                </gmd:northBoundLatitude>
            </gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
        </gmd:geographicElement>
        <gmd:temporalElement>
            <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
                <gmd:extent>
                <gml:TimePeriod xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" gml:id="id_1">
                    <gml:beginPosition/>
                    <gml:endPosition/>
                </gml:TimePeriod>
                </gmd:extent>
            </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
        </gmd:temporalElement>
    </gmd:EX_Extent>
</srv:extent>
```

Answer (score 1):

nmtoken is right, you need to request capabilities from the server. In your case you just need to add `gkt` (key) parameter with valid key value to the request:

```
https://gatekeeper1.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.nib_utm32_wmts_v2?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS&gkt=gkt_value
```

I sneaked gkt key from https://www.norgeskart.no/ site and got the following values (excerpt from GetCapabilities reply):

```
<ows:Identifier>Nibcache_UTM32_EUREF89_v2</ows:Identifier>
  <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832">
  <ows:LowerCorner>-2000000.0 3500000.0</ows:LowerCorner>
  <ows:UpperCorner>3545984.0 9045984.0</ows:UpperCorner>
  </ows:BoundingBox>
```

In your case origin (upper left corner) would be:

```
origin: [-2500000.0, 9045984.0]
```

And by the way, I never was able to get WMTS plugin to work correctly togeteher with proj4leaflet. I constructed WMTS tile request myself. In your case it would be something like:

```
var gkt = 'gkt_value';
var url = 'http://gatekeeper{s}.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.nib_utm32_wmts_v2?&gkt='
+ gkt +'&layer=Nibcache_UTM32_EUREF89&style=default&tilematrixset=default028mm&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix={z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}';

var layer = new L.TileLayer(url, {
  subdomains: ['1', '2', '3'],
  maxZoom: 16,
  minZoom: 0,
  attribution: ''    });

var resol = [
  21664, 10832, 5416, 2708, 1354, 677, 338.5, 169.25, 84.625, 42.3125, 21.15625, 10.578125, 5.2890625, 2.64453125, 1.322265625, 0.661132813, 0.330566406
];

var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25832','+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
   {
     origin: [-2000000.0, 9045984.0],
     bounds:  L.bounds( [-128543, 8015869], [1165657, 6381457]),
     resolutions: resol
   });

map = new L.Map('map', {
  crs: crs
});

map.addLayer(layer);
map.setView([59.877812, 8.590628], 5);
```

Comment: @ TomazicM

1) The WMS layer you are using above is for utm33 CRS but then using the crs information for utm 32.
2) The WMS is able to load when not specifying a CRS option but not with the correct CRS info
3) The WMS is not not projected correctly.  

I am trying to center on the following location
    setView([59.877812, 8.590628], 5);

But the map centers on the far north when it should be in the south near oslo. 

If you were not able to use proj4 to change the CRS any other ideas?

Comment: I added the revised code below

Comment: @wlavell Ups, sorry. I copy/pasted my existing code without noticing that it uses different crs. I corrected my answer and added additional code.